# Is it possible to rerun a failed pipeline on a different agent?

Tags: azure-devops

Should be a straightforward question, we had a pipeline run that failed on a hosted agent and we have been experimenting with switching to self-hosted as a test. Is there any way to re-run the failed job and get it to use a different agent pool? I suspect the answer is no but wanted to double check

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know not. Why because each run creates kind of snapshot of variables/parameters. So even if you parameterize pool it will be bound to value from the snapshot.

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but thanks for the response